# How to find file and print the content of the file by using find and cat (is it possible?)

Tags: linux, shell, find, pipe, cat

so I am fairly new at working with Linux and i was wondering if there is any way to use `find` commando to find a file in a location then pipeline it to print out (with `cat` commando) the content of that file you found to screen?

I've been trying the following thing, and obv it hasn't work. Can someone please help me?

```
find / -name hello.txt -type f 2>>/dev/null | cat hello.txt
```

This only prints out the file location of the hello.txt file;
`/home/user/exam/hello.txt` but how can i print the content of the file. Is it possible or should i just look into another solution. I've have noticed with all the CTF's I am trying to find atm, that having a way to do this would be very nice.

Also I was wondering if i also could do the same thing with example; `tee` commando. Save the content of the `txt` file to a file in my current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
find / -name hello.txt -type f -exec cat {} +
```

Comment: Thank you! I did this, and it worked. Also i found out if you add 2>>/dev/null to the end of the code you wrote, you don't get the 'permission denied' file locations up. You only get the content of the file. :D Cheers mate.

Is there anyway to write the content of the file into a new file with tee? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, you can always redirect output into a file using **>** (overwrite existing file if present) or **>>** (append to file if exists or create new file otherwise), so your command would be like **find / -name hello.txt -type f -exec cat {} + >> /path/to/newfile**

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it worked, sooo much easier ! Greetings